# API design for retrieving object from container that may not exists

Tags: c++, containers, api-design

What are the ways for creating API for retrieving object from indexed custom container, when the object in question may not exists?

So far I thought about:

1. Throw an exception

   ```
   T get(int index) const
   {
       if(not_exists(index)) throw std::out_of_range("Index is out of range");
       return get_base(index);
   }
   ```
2. Construct T and return it

   ```
   T get(int index) const
   {
       if(not_exists(index)) return T{};
       return get_base(index);
   }
   ```
3. Return bool and retrieve as reference

   ```
   bool get(int index, T & obj) const
   {
       if(not_exists(index)) return false;
       obj = get_base(index); return true;
   }
   ```
4. Use default argument if not found

   ```
   T get(int index, T def_obj) const
   {
       if(not_exists(index)) return def_obj;
       return get_base(index);
   }
   ```
5. Combine 4 + 2

   ```
   T get(int index, T def_obj = {}) const
   {
       if(not_exists(index)) return def_obj;
       return get_base(index);
   }
   ```
6. Modify container to add such object (warning - the `get` will no longer be `const`!)

   ```
   T get(int index, T def_obj = {})
   {
       if(not_exists(index)) set(index, def_obj);
       return get_base(index);
   }
   ```

What are the pros and cons of each solution? Have I missed anything?

I am especially worried about reasoning in heavily concurrent environment and I want to have as intuitive and safe API for client as possible.

Comment: boost::optional should a good option here.

Comment: @seccpur: why not `std::optional`?

Comment: Neither solution is a one size fits all. Many APIs offer several options for that reason. To take the standard library for example, that's why you have `container::find`, `container::at` and `container::operator[]`

Comment: @seccpur Can you post this as answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental issue here is of **semantics**: #1 and #3 are the only ones where presence is *distinguishable* from absence; #6 always succeeds in returning an *element* of the container; and the others always succeed in returning some *value*.  The application governs which of these you need.

In this regard, #1 and #3 are *complete*: either is sufficient for implementing any other (given some other means of adding elements to emulate #6).  If interference from other threads can be avoided, #4 and #5 are equally powerful: they can be used to detect absence by offering two different default values.  Alternatively, `bool contains(int index) const;` can be added to allow distinguishing absence (again with external synchronization as needed).

However, these emulations (except #2/4/5 from #1/3) involve repeated lookups that might have inadequate performance.  For some underlying data structures, yet other operations might be necessary for best performance: for example, moving an element from one index to another without reconstructing it.

Meanwhile, all of these approaches have practical issues, at least in a generic context.

1. Some experts [believe that `logic_error` is always a mistake](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0709r0.pdf); certainly throwing the exception in a reasonably common case is expensive.  However, a reference can be returned here, which is very useful.
2. `T` must be value-constructible (similar but not identical to *default*-constructible).
3. `T` must be assignable (and the client must have constructed one, perhaps used for multiple calls).  Undefined behavior can result from ignoring the flag (so mark it `[[nodiscard]]`).
4. Two `T` objects must be constructed per call.  The default could be made a reference to allow a reference return (and support a cumbersome form of detecting missing values), but to avoid allowing temporary arguments an rvalue-reference overload (or a constrained template) would then be required.
5. Like #4, this constructs two objects.  In a template context, improves on #2 in that value-constructibility is required only if the default value is *used*.
6. This could of course have three variations like #2/4/5.  It would be more useful if it returned a reference (like `map::operator[]`) to allow mutating the (potentially) new element.

If `T` might be expensive to construct (even from `{}`), only #1 (as used by `map::at`) and the [`optional` suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51061063/8586227) are efficient; conveniently they are also complete.  Perhaps the fastest variation is to return `const T*`, using a null pointer to indicate absence.  Picking between them is a question of fine-tuning performance trade-offs (unless your shop has it in for exceptions or pointers in general).  For a cheap `T`, #5 is attractive if its semantics suffice; otherwise #3 might be best (for its similarity to `if(std::cin >> x)`).

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet ( or std::optional in C++17)

```
boost::optional<T> get(int index, T& obj)
{
    if(not_exists(index))
        boost::none;
    else
        return get_base(index);
}
```